# Eclipse doesn't see anything in my src folder

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been trying to use a helpful tool called Forge.

It comes with the `src` folder and everything it really needs. I set up Eclipse, using the workspace as the `src` folder inside of the development folder. When Eclipse restarts, nothing is in the package explorer. I feel like I am doing something wrong. I have had other friends do the same thing, and it somehow worked for them. We are all using Eclipse Kepler, as well as the other friends. This version is easier to use, as it's STRICTLY (SOMEWHAT, apparently, which is based on the low amounts of research I did, but the high amounts that others have done. Thanks guys, :D) made for Java.

EDITED AND FIXED: Okay! I just figured out that Paul Crotty up there was right, I just messed up the paths. I literally went all [hacker typer](http://hackertyper.net) on this thing, and it worked. @Paul Crotty

Comment: Not to split hairs here, but Kepler isn't STRICTLY (gosh my ears hurt) for Java.

Comment: Did you import (or create) the project?

Comment: The workspace is supposed to be a couple of directories up from the src directories. Your directory structure should look like this workspace/project/src/. If you set your workspace/ as the src/ folder, no wonder you're not seeing anything as Eclipse is looking for the project folder inside your src/ directory (which it's not finding).

Comment: Have one of your friends set it up then.

Comment: Holy crap, didn't expect such amounts of responses in such little time. I'm trying Stephan's answer, and thanks, Chief, for the happy humor. :D    EDITED: Stephan's answer didn't work, any idea what to do?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://www.minecraftforge.net/wiki/Eclipse), always a good place to start, it says ...

> When you open Eclipse, when it asks to select a directory for your
> workspace, point it at the forge/mcp/eclipse folder in your forge
> directory.
>
> For advanced user only: Instead you can also create a new
> Java Project with the location forge/mcp/eclipse/Minecraft and adjust
> the the PATH variables of your project.

Comment: I believe that's for the old Forge. I don't see that directory, and research claims that is referencing older version of Forge.

Comment: "This page was last modified on 27 May 2014, at 12:23." That's pretty up-to-date. How does your file structure compare to the one [here](http://www.minecraftforge.net/wiki/Installation/Source); we are talking about the same Forge; right?

Comment: I'm currently using the 1.7.2 one, from the site.

Comment: Are you *certain* you're starting at the root of the directory. Previously you said you were in the development folder. @mattycfp

Comment: I put the Forge folder containing the src and stuff into another folder, then set the workspace as the folder I put the Forge folder into. It's folderception. @Chief Two Pencils

Comment: Okay, solution below! Not sure how... :D @Chief Two Pencils

Comment: @mattycfp: "solution below"; where? Did it just magically start working, what steps fixed the problem?

Answer (score 0):

No, no need to use the src folder as workspace. Put it somewhere else, cause every project you make will end up in the src folder and most likely mess up everything. When you get a different workspace, import the src folder. Then it should work. If you need help, just ask in the comments!

Comment: Don't have 50 rep yet, so I can't comment on your post, but, what Chief Two Pencils said. You can program in a crapload of different programming languages in Eclipse. Anyways, off topic for my post.

Comment: I think Matty only meant to say that he downloaded the third version down this list http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ which opens the Java perspective by default (obviously, the version of Eclipse for Java developers has nothing to do with the Kepler name itself, as Kepler doesn't prevent you from using other languages).

Answer (score 0):

While I am not a Minecraft player, I do know a few things about Eclipse.

I recommend trying the **Import** feature. From the Workspace/Package Explorer on the far left-hand side on the IDE, you can right click on the directory (usually the *package) into which you would like to import files and select the import option OR you can single lick on the same directory and go to the above toolbar File->Import.

Once the import window opens, make sure to select General->File System. Then Browse to the directory where your files are stored. (The path is usually something like
 'C:\User\UserName\workspace\Project_Name\src\package_name' on a Windows machine 
OR
 '/home/username/workspace/Project_name/src/package_name' on a Linux machine). 
Click 'OK' on bottom right-hand side. Then select the files or **packages you want to import!

*You may want to create a package as it is not recommended to store files in the 'default-package' created with most new Projects. (If you need to do this, you can right click on the src folder underneath the Project_Folder found in the Workspace/Package Directory and then go to New->Package. Name the package and your set!)

**Selecting a package will automatically import all files in that directory.

Comment: Okay, you are **VERY CLOSE** to being dead on. Though, I'm having problems. After clicking Finish and the files are all loaded, there are problems saying: Problems were encountered during import:
  Could not read from source when writing file 'C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\workspacefor Forge\Infallible\.metadata\.lock' and '
  The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file.' Not sure why, got any ideas? I also noticed that, instead of creating a new thing in src/java/whatever, it created one next to my entire Forge folder, which I put both into folders.

Comment: Please, help me out. I have to get this ready in 12 hours from now for me. I'm hosting a dev session, and I need this working for all of us.

Comment: I am glad to hear that you got it working! I am sorry I wasn't able to respond faster :/ (I was off the radar for a while due to work, school and a job interview). Feel free to ask if you need anything else! Good luck and happy mine crafting.